# useEffect not validating Boolean values to perform some action

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I using contextApi for state management, i have checkbox, on checked and unchecked, trying to dispatch ome actions to the store.
sample code:

```
import { store } from '../../../shared/store';
function GPSPosition() {

    const [isEnable, setCheckBoxEnable] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isEnable, "in use effect");
        setCheckBoxEnable(isEnable)
        console.log(isEnable, "in use effect after");
        if (isEnable) {
            dispatch({
                type: "stopsendingdata",
                stop_sending: isEnable,
                data: 'GPS'
            })
        } else {
            console.log("send latest values to backend");
            console.log(isEnable);
            form.validateFields()
                .then((values) => {
                    // Submit values
                    // submitValues(values);
                    dispatch({
                        type: "updateGPSCoordinates",
                        latitude: values.latitude,
                        longitude: values.longitude,
                        altitude: values.altitude,
                    });

                })
                .catch((errorInfo) => { });

        }
    }, [isEnable]);

return(

    <div className="homepage-widget-header">
        <div className="text-ellipsis">{GpsConstants.WIDGET_NAME}</div>
          <Checkbox checked={isEnable} onChange={() => setCheckBoxEnable(!isEnable)} className="homepage- 
       widget-checkbox text-ellipsis" >{HomepageConst.CHECKBOX_HEADER}</Checkbox>
    </div>
)
}
```

In useEffect not validating checkbox state, when i load application both if else cases are executing,

The main idea is i want to access checkbox state from different places,

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first `setCheckBoxEnable`? If I'm not mistaken, it's set to false from the beginning, and with the first one, you're once again setting it to false, and therefore only the `else` should be fired right?

Comment: check this line in return ``onChange={() => setCheckBoxEnable(!isEnable)}``, onChange of checkbox the new value already set which is true, so it should not be false,